# How to make multiple requests to Yahoo Finance to get around the 200 stock limit?

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed an Excel sheet (with help from another online tutorial) that pulls stock information from Yahoo Finance. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim Symbols As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 200
    Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & i).Value & "+"
Next i
Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=sl1w1t8ee8rr5s6j4m6kjp5"
Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Http.Open "GET", URL, False
Http.Send

Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)
Dim sLine As String
For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)
    If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
        Values = Split(sLine, ",")
        W.Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Values(1)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Right(Replace(Values(2), Chr(34), ""), 7)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(3)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(4)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value = Values(5)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = Values(6)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 12).Value = Values(7)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 13).Value = Values(8)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 14).Value = Values(9)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 15).Value = Values(10)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 16).Value = Values(11)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 17).Value = Values(12)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 18).Value = Values(13)
    End If
Next i
W.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

The problem I am having is that if I have more than 200 stock tickers in column A, it comes back with an error because you cannot make a request that has more than 200 ticker symbols. My question is how can I modify this code so that it will request the information for the first 200 stocks then put in the data, then move to the next 200 stocks and put in its data and so on until it has gone through every symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of your function will break the requests into a maximum of 100 symbols at a time. The results for all symbols are collected into `Resp` before proceeding to the next phase.

Note that the earlier response has a bug: results for symbols 200+ will overwrite the results from the first batch of symbols.

```
    Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
    Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
    If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim Symbols As String
    Dim Resp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Http As WinHttpRequest
    Resp = ""
    Symbols = ""
    For i = 2 To Last
        If Symbols <> "" Then Symbols = Symbols & "+"
        Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & i).Value
        If i Mod 100 = 1 Or i = Last Then       ' do at most 100 symbols at a time
            URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=sl1w1t8ee8rr5s6j4m6kjp5"
            Set Http = New WinHttpRequest
            Http.Open "GET", URL, False
            Http.Send
            Resp = Resp & Http.ResponseText
            Symbols = ""
        End If
    Next i
    Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)
    '' remaining code is unchanged
```

...Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second loop (index j) and specify the upper boundary as shown in the following code snippet:

```
    Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Cells(W.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim Symbols As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim jMax As Integer: jMax = Int(Last / 200)
    For j = 0 To jMax
        For i = 1 To 200
            If j * 200 + i <= Last Then
                Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & j * 200 + i).Value & "+"
            End If
        Next i

Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=sl1w1t8ee8rr5s6j4m6kjp5"
Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Http.Open "GET", URL, False
Http.Send

Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)
Dim sLine As String
For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)
    If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
        Values = Split(sLine, ",")
        W.Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Values(1)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Right(Replace(Values(2), Chr(34), ""), 7)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(3)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(4)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value = Values(5)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = Values(6)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 12).Value = Values(7)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 13).Value = Values(8)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 14).Value = Values(9)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 15).Value = Values(10)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 16).Value = Values(11)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 17).Value = Values(12)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 18).Value = Values(13)
    End If
Next i
W.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    Next j
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,